# Prompting for username/pw with JDBC: where is that prompt coming from and where do my properties go?

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-midrange

I am using JDBC with the IBM toolbox to connect to tables on an AS400 server. When I establish a connection, I do not supply a username or a password to the URL, so I want the system to prompt the user. I don't want to hard-code any passwords or automatically put the admin password in. Bad idea. So prompt it is. I shove all my other settings into a property object and send it off:

```
prop = setProperties(false, //ensure the server always prompts for logon information
                "","",SCHEMA);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://" + IP_ADDRESS, prop);
```

My property-setting function looks like this:

```
private Properties setProperties(boolean local,String USER_ID,
        String PASSWORD,String SCHEMA)
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("naming", "system");
    prop.put("errors", "full");
    prop.put("libraries", SCHEMA + ", *LIBL");
    if (!local) {
        prop.put("user", USER_ID);
        prop.put("password", PASSWORD);
    }
    return prop;
}  // serverProperties
```

Since I don't supply a un or pw, I get this nifty little box:

[image: username/password prompt]

1. Where does this box come from? Is this a JDBC thing or an IBM toolbox thing? And can I intercept it? I'm curious to know if I can skin it. When I translate this project from desktop to android, I want to be able to spawn an android UI (since android doesn't know swing or awt).
2. if I check those two checkboxes, no matter how many connections I open and close, whatever I put into those un/pw fields persists. Is there a way to grab that un/pw data from somewhere? I tried grabbing the connection properties object, but all the fields come back blank to me. [IBM Toolbox properties documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzahh/jdbcproperties.htm) lists what properties to expect (I'm only interested in the general properties at this moment), but doesn't actually tell me where I can retrieve those properties.

This

```
Properties prop = connection.getClientInfo();
System.out.print(prop.toString());
```

yields me this`{ClientProgramID=, ClientUser=, ApplicationName=, ClientHostname=, ClientAccounting=}`
Not even close to what I should be expecting. I'm not sure where my properties go.

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 1):

That is the toolbox default prompt when no explicit user or password is provided in the connection URL:

[image: General properties]

If you want to skin or otherwise have more control you should create your own custom user interface and specify the user and password properties when you open the connection.

See the [IBM Toolbox for Java JDBC properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/jdbcproperties.htm) for more information.

Comment: Makes sense. One question down. So. If I prompt for information, do you know where it gets stored? It has to be somewhere because the connection doesn't ask me to log in for each connection after the first one. It's not in the connection properties.